# Как добавить проверку свойств в PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, валидация, propertygrid

Имеется ли стандартный механизм проверки значений свойств в [PropertyGrid](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid?view=netframework-4.7.2)?
На данный момент добавляю обработчик на событие [PropertyValueChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.propertyvaluechanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) и выглядит это более чем коряво:

```cs
private void propertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged(object s, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ChangedItem.PropertyDescriptor.Name)
    {
        case nameof(MyType.Name):
            string newName = (string)e.ChangedItem.Value;
            if (!isValideName(newName))
            {
                ShowError("The \"Name\" property is invalid!");
                e.ChangedItem.PropertyDescriptor.SetValue(propertyGrid1.SelectedObject, e.OldValue);
            }
            break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

При таком подходе событие не будет срабатывать для "вложенных" редакторов.
Ещё можно выбрасывать исключения в сеттерах свойств. В этом случае PropertyGrid сам будет отображать ошибки:

[image: Ошибка при выбрасывании исключения в сеттерах PropertyGrid]

В идеале хотелось бы просто декорировать свойства атрибутами [DataAnnotations](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=netframework-4.7.2) (напр. [Range](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Required](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2), [RegularExpression](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)) и на их основе выполнять проверку.
Как выполнить проверку свойств в PropertyGrid?

Comment: [PropertyGrid FAQ](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml) - это смотрели?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, конечно. Но там ничего такого нет.